# How to filter optional NSMutableSet in core data many to many relationship?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have two core data entity that has many to many relationship, lets say user and project entity with the following attributes.

```
extension Project {
    @NSManaged var project: String?
    @NSManaged var projectId: String?
    @NSManaged var user: NSMutableSet?
}

extension User {
    @NSManaged var address: String?
    @NSManaged var dateOfBirth: String?
    @NSManaged var email: String?
    @NSManaged var firstName: String?
    @NSManaged var lastName: String?
    @NSManaged var phoneNumber: String?
    @NSManaged var userId: String?
    @NSManaged var username: String?
    @NSManaged var projects: NSMutableSet?
}
```

Now, i have table view which show all list of project and have a function to filter the project by user.
Here is my filter function.

```
func getFilteredProjects() {
    //projectArray holds all project data
    //loggedInUser is an user instance
    filteredProjectArray = projectArray.filter({ $0.user!.containsObject(loggedInUser) }) 

    projectTableView.reloadData()
}
```

In above code, i had to force unwrap optional user set.
i am afraid that using that piece of code will break my application if the user set is nil (which could happen depends on deletion rule).
My question is, is there any way to filter optional `NSMutableSet` without force unwrapping it?

Comment: You could apply use a `flatMap` prior to the `filter` to safely unwrap `user` set(s?). E.g. `projectArray.flatMap{ $0.user }.filter{ $0.containsObject(loggedInUser) }`

Comment: @dfri: I see, so you are suggesting two level process right? first to create array that filtering nil user using `flatMap` and then further filtering it based on user. Thanks for your suggestion, i will definitely try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use optional chaining (not compiler tested):

```
projectArray.filter { $0.user?.containsObject(loggedInUser) == true }
```

But the "Core Data way" would be to execute a fetch request
on the "Project" entity with a predicate

```
NSPredicate(format: "ANY user = %@", loggedInUser)
```

Comment: I just want to filtering the array since i already have all project data fetched from core data. i am assuming that filtering array will use less resource than doing two connection to database (one to get all and one to get filtered data). i might be wrong though.

Comment: @setonugroho: The advantage of the second method  is that it can be used with a fetched results controller, and you'll get live updates of the filtered data. – But it is up to you, the first method should work as well.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion, i'll try the first method later. As for fetched results controller, i have already created my view controller with all of its constraint set up, so i'm looking for a way with less effort to implement this and table view fits my needs.

Comment: @setonugroho: Any feedback?

Comment: Sorry, this take so long. Initially, i implemented solution provided by @dfri to create new array that filtering nil user and then further filtering it later. But now, i'm gonna implement yours as i think it would be too much to create new array for this problem.